# Subclassing Inner Class from Outer Class versus other Inner Class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I am befuddled why this is allowed

```
public class Foo {
    class Bar extends Foo {
    }
}
```

Yet this is not allowed

```
public class Foo {
    class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    class Fooey extends Bar {
    }
}
```

The compiler informed that it can not reference Fooey.this before supertype constructor has been called.

And this is allowed

```
public class Foo {
    static class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    class Fooey extends Bar {
    }
}
```

What is going on here? And where can I go to find more information on how inner class inheritance works?

**EDIT** I came upon both rather poor ideas; inner class extends outer class and inner class extends other static inner class. I wasn't sure what exactly was going and how I should refactor this. I ended up just yanking out the inner classes and encapsulating them in the outer class.

Comment: Check out this question, pretty sure this duplicates it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: Not a dupe (at least not of that one).

Comment: What's the use of having an outer instance of a class that you're extending?

Comment: @Jorn, I came upon both issues when looking to refactor old code. yes, something that awful was in a production environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: Don't do this sort of thing. It's evil. Really, Java 1.1 should have been specified very much more restrictively, IMO.

There is confusion about which `this` to use from the `Foo.Fooey` constructor. The outer this (`Foo.this`) would work. But the actual `this` is a `Foo` but it can't be passed to the superconstructor because of rules about using `this` before the superconstructor returns (and besides having an outer instance the same instance as the inner instance is fecked up). The outer this on the superclass "`((Bar)this).this$0`" (IIRC), is also inaccessible due to restrictions on use of `this`.

The solution is to be explicit. Explicit is usually a good thing in my book (unless it becomes boilerplate).

```
public class Foo {
    class Bar extends Foo {

    }

    class Fooey extends Bar {
        Fooey() {
            Foo.this.super();
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet, don't have an inner class extend its own outer class, or extend any inner class.

Comment: +1 for your first remark. 
If you have to explicitly make a constructor, because the default one doesn't compile, I'd say you're doing it wrong (design wise).

Comment: Tom, thanks for the answer. I came upon both rather poor ideas; inner class extends outer class and inner class extends other static inner class. I wasn't sure what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the JLS and the answers to this question are a starting point

[Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

[Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

Tom Hawtin answer is correct.

Have also a look at [java puzzler](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/). The sample chapter contains this case and a few other "interesting" case you may want to have a look at.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment yet - I need 50 rep)

I'm also befuddled that this is allowed. A (non-static) inner class of an outer class is actually a member of that outer class. Read: an inner object is a member of its outer object. (Incidentally, every outer object *must* own an inner object but this is besides the point.)

The analogy I like to use is this: let `Car` be the outer class and let `Wheel` be the inner class. Every instance of `Car` must, and does, have at least one instance of `Wheel` as a member.

Now it doesn't make conceptual sense for an inner class to extend an outer class. I can't think of any real-world situations that call for an object being both a member and a type of another object. Set Theorists will recall the *[Axiom of Regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)* and its consequences.

Think of it this way: Let `Honda` extend `Car`, and let `Honda` be an inner class nested inside `Car`. What you're saying here is that every `Honda` object **is a** `Car` object (duh), and every `Car` object **has a** `Honda` object. Only one of these statements makes sense, but both are allowed to be true in Java.

Or back to the previous analogy, you shouldn't let `Wheel` extend `Car` because then a `Wheel` would **be** a `Car`, and by definition must **have** another `Wheel`, which by the way **is a** `Car` and so must **have a** `Wheel` and forever and ever Amen. Constructing a `Car` object would result in an infinite loop of nested objects.

I'm upset that this is legal and does not produce a compile-time error.

Comment: Imagine how upset you would be if you saw it in production code!

Comment: If Honda extends Car, it does *not* mean every Car object has a Honda Object.

Comment: @RAY: yes but if Honda is nested inside Car (a.k.a. a "member" of Car) then it *does* mean every Car object has a Honda object.

Comment: Not true. If Honda is an inner class of Car, a Car object does not necessarily have a Honda object. On the other hand, a Honda object must have a reference to the parent Car object. You need to be able to differentiate between a member class and a member variable.

Comment: Understood. Would I be correct in supposing that a Car object has a Honda object only if the `Car` class contains the line: `private Honda accord;`?